# Como obter a versão do Android e o tamanho da RAM do dispositivo?

Tags: android

Estou a desenvolver um app que verifica a Versao Android e o Tamanho da Memoria Ram.

Como posso obter essas informações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A versão do Android pode ser obtida através da classe [Build.VERSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).

```
String release = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Valores, em Mb, relativos à memória RAM podem ser obtidos assim:

```
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long memoriaLivre = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
long memoriaTotal = mi.totalMem / 1048576L;
long memoriaEmUso = totalMemory - freeMemory;
```

O valor de [totalMem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html#totalMem) é a memória total disponível ao kernel, que é aproximadamente igual ao total de memória RAM.

Comment: OBRIGADO VALEU AJUDOU MUITO